# angular2 zone.js http error

Tags: http, angular, zone.js

I am using angular2 and I make up an http request, in case of error I catch the error and throw them as an observable. But I can still see that zone.js error as follows:

POST http://localhost:8000/users 500 (Internal Server Error)

I can see the error is raised directly after making the request as follows

```
(here is error)zone.js?1489709556352:1805 POST http://localhost:8000/users 500 (Internal Server Error)
zone.js?1489709556352:1805 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8000/users".
```

Is this a normal case and I can ignore these errors.

Regards

Comment: would you please provide more information, how you are covering error in catch to observable and what is your code? there is no enough information for this question

Comment: Sorry, this was in an old project. I Just ignore it since it does not affect the functionality.